# Jasmine + karma + angular test create controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Where I make mistake? How can I get instance of controller in Jasmine + angular? How can I resolve controller? I have no idea what should I use to resolve that.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.contact', ['ui.router'])
.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.contact = {
        name: 'John Doe'
    };
}]);


describe('myApp.contact module tests', function () {
    var scope, createController;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        createController = function () {
            return $controller('contactCtrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        };
    }));

    it('contact name is John Doe', function () {
        var controller = createController();
        expect(controller).toEqual('John Doe');
    });
});

myApp.contact module tests
    ✗ contact name is John Doe
        Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'contactCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/ng/areq?p0=contactCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
            at E:/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
            at assertArg (E:/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1816:11)
            at assertArgFn (E:/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1826:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had missed several things here

1. You need to initialize angular module to make your controller & all other components available by doing `module('myApp.contact')` in your before each so that `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'contactCtrl' is not a function, got undefined` will went away.
2. Then inside your Assert statement of test you should use `scope` object instead of `controller`(you could use controller when your properties are bounded to `this`)
3. Don't forget to refer `contactCtrl.js` & `ui-router.js` on page.

   ```
   expect(scope.contact.name).toEqual('John Doe');
   ```

**Code**

```
describe('myApp.contact module tests', function () {
    var scope, createController;
    beforeEach(module('myApp.contact')); //1st change

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        createController = function () {
            return $controller('contactCtrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        };
    }));

    it('contact name is John Doe', function () {
        var controller = createController();
        expect(scope.contact.name).toEqual('John Doe'); //2nd change
    });
});
```

Comment: module(myApp.contact); says myApp is undefined, I try change this to module('myApp.contact'); Error: Injector already created, can not register a module! In karma.conf.js I have all files included

Comment: @PeterPan wrap it with single quote, I missed that one

Comment: I wrap it first time, but that throws: Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!

Comment: @PeterPan that was happening because we are using `function inject()` inside `beforeEach`, before module initialization, we should load angular module first.

Comment: OK, how can I do that?